# What should I index mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I'm looking to speed this query up. I currently have an index on

```
users_score.appID
app_names.name

SELECT users_scores.username, users_scores.avatar, users_scores.score
FROM users_scores
RIGHT JOIN app_names ON app_names.id = users_scores.appID
WHERE app_names.name =  "testapp1"
ORDER BY users_scores.score DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Basically every column that appears in the JOIN or WHERE or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Include in your question the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT users_scores.username, users_scores.avatar, users_scores.score
FROM users_scores
RIGHT JOIN app_names ON app_names.id = users_scores.appID
WHERE app_names.name =  "testapp1"
ORDER BY users_scores.score DESC ` and you will wind up learning how to figure this out for *any* query...

Comment: One thing I'd note aside from general query optimization is that the table app_names is being right joined when an inner join would appear to suffice - not only that, the join isn't really required at all if your application knows the app_names.id it needs to find scores for - then you're simply requiring an index on users_scores.appID

Comment: @PaulDixon I'm using the right join simply based on profiling speed tests. I was using an inner join but the query was taking twice as long to run vs a right join. Also the application wont know what ID it needs to use it will find that by looking at that table using the app name.

Comment: Okay I set it to inner join now. Not sure what the profiling was picking up on but it was running almost twice as slow with the inner vs the right last night. Today it's blazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an index on your primary key? (`users_score.id`, or whatever you've named it). If not, keys should always be indexed...  in fact, they ARE the index. `app_names.id` should also be primary key/index.

appID is a good index, however I see you searching for apps via name. It's faster if MySQL doesn't have to perform string comparisons on `WHERE` clauses. It would be much more efficient to search for an AppID. Given the app name is known ('testapp1'), you could do an inner query to determine the ID before searching, like this.

`WHERE app_names.id = (SELECT id FROM app_names WHERE app_names.name = "testapp1")`

Comment: This is what I love about stackoverflow. I would have never guessed that running 2 queries would be faster then 1. After putting this in the query it went from being 1-1.5 seconds to 0.000112 seconds.

Comment: Wow! I expected an improvement, but that's amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `RIGHT JOIN`. Any `RIGHT JOIN` can and should be written as a `LEFT JOIN`.

Regardless, your `WHERE` clause automatically turns the query into an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT users_scores.username, users_scores.avatar, users_scores.score
FROM app_names
INNER JOIN users_scores
ON users_scores.appID = app_names.id
WHERE app_names.name = 'testapp1'
ORDER BY users_scores.score DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Since you're not returning any data from app_names, you can get rid of the JOIN entirely by using a subquery:

```
SELECT username, avatar, score
FROM users_scores
WHERE appID = (SELECT id FROM app_names WHERE name = 'testapp1' LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 30
```

MySQL executes non-correlated subqueries first, so MySQL can use an index on the app_names table for the search, then is able to utilize an index on users_scores for the search and sort.

For optimum read performance, add a multi-column index on `user_scores(appID, score)` to satisfy the search and the sort, or with an even larger *covering index*: `user_scores(appID, score, username, avatar)`.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN is simply a flipped LEFT JOIN -- why is it "bad"?

Comment: It's not commonly used (and not widely supported). [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) say: *RIGHT JOIN works analogously to LEFT JOIN. To keep code portable across databases, it is recommended that you use LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN.*

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  users_scores.username, users_scores.avatar, users_scores.score
    FROM  users_scores
    RIGHT JOIN app_names                 -- Probably forces app_names to be first
              ON app_names.id
                  = users_scores.appID   -- users_scores second; Step 1
    WHERE  app_names.name = "testapp1"   -- app_names first; Step 1
    ORDER BY  users_scores.score DESC
    LIMIT  0 , 30
```

app_names needs `INDEX(name)`

users_scores needs `INDEX(appID)`

Even if you remove `RIGHT` (which might be noise), the Optimizer will pick `app_names` first because of the `WHERE` clause mentions only `app_names`.

All of this, plus more, is found in my blog on [Creating an Index from a SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: And it was downgraded because of ...?